# opacity-based image transition functions really bad

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

How can i make a better image transition?

Opacity method is not ok because it causes the images to blink
or im doing something wrong. if so, please help :)

```
<img class="image" id="image1">
        <img class="image hidden" id="image2">
```

```
.image {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            pointer-events: all;
            border-radius: 12px;
            background: black;
            height: 90vh;
            transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
        }
        .hidden {
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

```
var cycled = false;
        function getActiveImage() {
            return document.getElementById(cycled ? "image1" : "image2");
        }
        function displayImage(img) {
            getActiveImage().src = img;
            document.getElementById("image1").classList.toggle("hidden");
            document.getElementById("image2").classList.toggle("hidden");
            cycled = !cycled;
        }
```

Comment: At some point during the 0.5 second transition `opacity` gets switched from `1` to `0`. CSS does not incorporate an automatic mechanism that smoothly transitions from 1 to 0 and back. You need a `@keyframe` definition and use CSS [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) to transition `opacity` per keyframe.

Comment: like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1L05xzs9/20)?

Comment: Seems to work like I had in mind. I created a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npqt3yvd/) with two different random photos and increased the delay a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved. turns out images aren't blending properly
so i made one image an overlay; same code, but without toggling image1 class